# Kolmogorov's zero-one law and triviality of tail sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I study ergodic theory and K-automorphisms in particular. One of the equivalent definitions of $K$-system demands trivial tail sigma-algebra. So I came up with the following question:

$\textbf{Kolmogorov's zero-one law}$

Consider probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ and let $\mathcal F_n$ be a sequence of **independent** sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal A$. Consider $\sigma$-algebra
$$\mathcal F= \bigwedge\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigvee\limits_{k=n}^\infty \mathcal F_k$$

Then $\forall E\in \mathcal F$ either $\mathbb P(E)=0$ or $\mathbb P(E)=1.$

---

So my question is: **does this theorem imply triviality of $\mathcal F$**, i. e.  $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing, \Omega\}$?

For me it's almost obvious that **no** - because triviality is much more stronger property. But I don't know how to see it - may be there's an example in which I can see this sigma-algebra is not trivial, but still probabilities of all sets are either $0$ 0r $1$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: $\mathcal F_k=\mathcal F=\{\emptyset, A, A^{c},\Omega\}$ where $P(A)=0$. Indepedence hypothesis is satisfied in this example.

Comment: You mean $E=A? $

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo.

Comment: Thank you for your example, such simple! Don't know why, I thought it would be tough!

Answer (score 1):

In ergodic theory, the trivial $\sigma$-algebra is not the algebra $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, it is the $\sigma$-algebra containing all negligible sets and their complements. The Kolmogorov 0-1 law asserts the triviality of the tail $\sigma$-algebra in that sense.

Two $\sigma$-algebras are said to be equal mod 0 if for any set $A$ in one of the algebras, there is a set $A'$ in the other such that $\mu(A \Delta A') = 0$. All equalities should be considered mod 0.

Comment: I have seen this $\textrm{mod}\ 0$ approach in Walters, but did not apply it in this case, now I see it, thanks!